# ASP.NET MVC controller execute raw SQL queries - ToList objects are null

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I want to use some raw SQL queries in my ASP.NET MVC controller. My queries are much more complicated than the example shown, but they has the same problems.

The objects are empty!

TableName

```
| Id | Column01 | Column02 | 
+----+----------+----------+
| 1  | Peter    | Shaw     |
| 2  | Justus   | Jonas    |
| 3  | Andrew   | Miller   |
```

Here is my example class that I use for the list.

```
public class MyList
{
    public string Column01
    public string Column02
}
```

```
string query = "SELECT Column01, Column02 FROM TableName";

var result = db.Database.SqlQuery<MyList>(query).ToList();
```

The `result` is a list with 3 entries. Every entry has `Column01` and `Column02` but their value is `null`.

I think the database connection works because of the counter shows 3 entries.

Does anybody have an idea how it works?

Comment: You are using Entity and I think the mapping is not current.  I think you may need to do a migration.  I suspect the column order is different so you are mapping to the wrong columns.  See following for how Entity works : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/walkthrough-simple-object-model-and-query-csharp?force_isolation=true

Comment: Have you tried making those **properties** (instead of fields) - `public string Column01 { get; set; }` in your `MyList` class ....

Comment: @marc_s: Your are going right, thanks. That's the way it goes.

Comment: I can't help but observe... if you use [QueryFirst](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QkJDccYSw8A) this all just works. The MyList class is generated for you (so guaranteed to align with the results). Your sql lives in a .sql file, validated, with intellisense. And a if a query returns no lines, you get an empty list. Disclaimer - I wrote QueryFirst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use  `{ get; set; }`  in the class

```
public class MyList
{
    public string Column01 { get; set; }
    public string Column02 { get; set; }
}
```